# Python socket errno -3 on run

Tags: python, sockets, irc

Upon running and testing a few IRC bots on a old laptop running Lucid puppy 5.2 after installing Python 1.6 (the only python .pet i could find), every few times i run the python file, i get this strange error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "bot.py!, line 77, in <module>
       irc.connect ( (irc_network, irc_port) ) 
    File "<string>", Line 1, in connect
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

this is the section of code this error is occouring on:

```
irc_network = 'irc.esper.net'
irc_port = 5555
irc = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
irc.connect ( ( irc_network, irc_port ) )
```

I'm just using the `socket` module for this, with no third party imports of any kind.
I have no idea what this error is and what it means, as a quick google turned up nothing for me.

The purplexing fact is that i can just try and run the bot again, without changing anything, and it runs fine.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: is `irc_network` a host name, or an ip address?

Comment: The reason I ask is the error seems related to DNS and would make sense if you were connecting to, say, `irc.freenode.net` instead of an ip address and the DNS server took too long to respond.

Comment: This is connecting to the Espernet IRC, with irc.esper.net, and the port 5555.

Comment: Try using one of these instead then: 80.65.51.138, 91.205.185.104, 178.79.132.147, 204.152.221.218, 72.14.191.81.

Comment: @sberry Using one of those IP's (i did 72.14.191.81) instead of irc.esper.net gives me this: "socket.error: [errno 22] Invalid argument", so i don't think i can use an direct IP to connect to espernet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only I can think of that your DNS resolver doesn't work as it should. Here this code runs fine.

---

BTW (just as a comment), if you replace

```
irc = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
irc.connect ( ( irc_network, irc_port ) )
```

with

```
irc = socket.create_connection( ( irc_network, irc_port ) )
```

you are more future proof as you don't restrict yourself to an old protocol which will disappear in the next decades.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, so do you think reinstalling python would resolve my issue?

Comment: try `host irc.esper.net`at the command line. If it gives a useful answer, it is Python to blame, otherwise your system.

Comment: I just saw that it only happens from time to time. How often does that happen?

Comment: For some reason almost every first run, then again once every 3-6 runs of the program. Running `host irc.esper.net` results in `bash: host: command not found`

Comment: @user1362461 That is very strange. How does the `host` call above react? Only every now and then as well, or always?

Comment: There is no host commad on my prompt at all, so i can't do that for some reason.

Comment: and other means of name resolution? `ping`, `dig`, `nslookup`?

Comment: only the ping command worked, that retured "91.205.185.104", and then using this, my bot could connect. I ran this and now the socket errors are gone.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.  It turns out my DNS could not resolve my host name, yes sloppy to have given my host just the name and not host.node1.node2.  So look up your host name, and if it does not work, then you need to be more specific, basically you are looking for your DNS A or Quad A record, and use the name that your DNS can resolve. The other possibility is that you do not have a DNS listing yet.

Comment: I just got this problem on my docker app. And I got a feeling that your answer is the better one. Would you please be more specific?